# Geocoding API denying access though API key whitelisted for referrer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

OK ... I feel like I'm going insane.

So I've enabled the geocoding API on Google Console (and a host of other things), and put in every reasonable permutation of my referrer

[image: API settings]

Then I do a `GET` request to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json` via client JavaScript, with the args as (CoffeeScript) `args = "components=postal_code:#{zip}|country:US&key=#{apiKey}"`

Yet, the response I get from the server is:

[image: API Response]

WHICH HAS MY SERVER REFERRER IN IT. Which, as you can see from the first screenshot, is a whitelisted domain. It's a browser API key from JavaScript, which is the appropriate one ... yet insanity?

I am sure I'm missing something, but perhaps I can't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: `#{apiKey}` ... what does that mean? a `#` followed by the key? or is it just the key?

Comment: @JaromandaX in CoffeeScript, that's how you can in-line concatenate. So, `foo='bar'` then `baz = "value of foo: #{foo}"` will give `baz = "value of foo: bar"`. On the error, I validated the args value, but snipped it out of the screenshot (it's good).